# When are $(a_1,...,a_n)\in \mathbb{A}_i^n$ and $(b_1,...,b_n)\in \mathbb{A}_j^n$ for some $i < j$ equal to each other?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Let $\mathbb{P}^n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \mathbb{A}_i^n$, where each $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is an affine space $\mathbb{A}_i^n = \mathbb{A}^n$, and where the  $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Suppose $(a_1,...,a_n)\in \mathbb{A}_i^n$ and $(b_1,...,b_n)\in \mathbb{A}_j^n$  for some $i < j$. Write down necessary
and sufficient conditions for these points to be equal in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

attempt: Here $\mathbb{P}^n$ is viewed as $\mathbb{A}^n$ along with an extra point for every possible slope of a line. To see that $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ is dense in $\mathbb{P}^n$, notice that we can pick a point $a \in \mathbb{P}^n/\mathbb{A}^n$ such that we can find an open set containing $a$, but not intersecting $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Recall that $\mathbb{A}^n$ is the affine space and is defined as $\mathbb{A}^n = {\{a = (a_1,..,a_n): a_i \in K}\}$ . 
Then consider if $i=2$ and $j = 3$. Then using $\mathbb{A}_i^n = \mathbb{A}^n$, we have $\mathbb{P}^n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \mathbb{A}_i^n =  \mathbb{A}_1^n \cup  \mathbb{A}_2^n =  \mathbb{A}^n \cup  \mathbb{A}^n$, and a point in  $\mathbb{A}_1^n$ looks as $(a_1)$, and in $\mathbb{A}_2^n$ as $(a_1, a_2)$, thus it's intersection is $(a_1,a_2)$. And if $j = 3$ , we have $\mathbb{P}^n = \bigcup_{i=0}^n \mathbb{A}_i^n =  \mathbb{A}_1^n \cup  \mathbb{A}_2^n \cup \mathbb{A}_3^n =  \mathbb{A}^n \cup  \mathbb{A}^n \cup \mathbb{A}^n$, where a point in $\mathbb{A}_1^n$ looks as $(b_1)$ and in $\mathbb{A}_2^n$ looks as $(b_1,b_2)$ and in in $\mathbb{A}_3^n$ looks as $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$, so their intersection is $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$. Thus, for $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ to be equal, we would need an extra coordinate, $\mathbb{P}^n$ . I am not sure what would the necessary and sufficient conditions for these two points to be equal. Could someone please help? Than you in advance.

Comment: It seems like you are misunderstanding what $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ means. The index $i$ is not specifying how many coordinates there are. You incorrectly claimed $\mathbb{P}^n = \mathbb{A}_1^n \cup \mathbb{A}_2^n$, but it should be $\mathbb{P}^n = \mathbb{A}_0^n \cup \dots \cup \mathbb{A}_n^n$, which is $n+1$ copies of $\mathbb{A}^n$.

Comment: yes I forgot that it starts at $i = 0$ and $j=0$

Comment: There is a bigger issue at hand than where your index started. For example, based on your last paragraph you don't seem to understand that $\mathbb{A}_1^n$ has $n$ coordinates, not $1$ coordinate.

Comment: What you wrote is correct, but later in your paragraph you said "$\mathbb{A}_1^n$ looks like $(b_1)$, $\mathbb{A}_2^n$ looks like $(b_1,b_2)$" and so on, which is nonsensical. 

Anyway, as for a hint, remember that $\mathbb{A}_i^n$ embeds in $\mathbb{P}^n$ by sending $(a_1,\dots, a_n) \mapsto (a_1: \dots : a_{i-1}: 1 : a_{i}: \dots : a_n)$, meaning you stick $1$ into the $i$th slot. Think about when two of these match for different $i$'s.

Comment: I think you are on the right track now. Careful, I think you meant to write $b_j\neq 0$ in the second line you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let us assume $i<j$ (if $i=j$ the the problem is trivial). The point in $\Bbb P^n$ associated to $(a_1, \dots, a_n)$ is $[a_1, \dots, a_{i-1}, 1, a_i, \dots, a_n]$ with $1$ on the $i$-th position and $[,]$ denoting projective coordinates. The point in $\Bbb P^n$ associated to $(b_1, \dots, b_n)$ is $[b_1, \dots, b_{j-1}, 1, b_j, \dots, b_n]$ with $1$ on the $j$-th position. Now remember that two $(n+1)$-uples represent the same point if and only if one is a *non-zero* multiple of the other. Therefore, it is necessary and sufficient to require that there exist $\lambda \ne 0$ such that

$$[a_1, \dots, a_{i-1}, 1, a_i, \dots, a_n] = [\lambda b_1, \dots, \lambda b_{j-1}, \lambda , \lambda b_j, \dots, \lambda b_n] .$$

Equating the $i$-th coordinates gives us $1 = \lambda b_i$. This imposes that $b_i \ne 0$ and $\lambda = \dfrac 1 {b_i}$, whence the above condition may be rewritten as

$$[a_1, \dots, a_{i-1}, 1, a_i, \dots, a_n] = \left[ \frac {b_1} {b_i}, \dots, \frac {b_{j-1}} {b_i}, \frac 1 {b_i}, \frac {b_j} {b_i}, \dots, \frac {b_n} {b_i} \right] ,$$

whence by a componentwise comparison it follows that the necessary and sufficient conditions are

$$\begin{cases} a_k = \dfrac {b_k} {b_i}, & k \le i-1, \\
a_k = \dfrac {b_{k+1}} {b_i}, &  i \le k \le j-2, \\
a_{j-1} = \dfrac 1 {b_i}, \\
a_k = \dfrac {b_k} {b_i}, & k \ge j .\end{cases}$$